# RequireJS shim of bundled module not working

Tags: requirejs

I am defining a module inside a bundle. The module needs shimming. The problem is that if I load the module not in a bundle, it works fine but as soon as I put it in a bundle, it won't work. So 'blazybundled' won't return Blazy object while 'blazyfile' will.

```
   require.config({
        baseUrl: './js/',
        paths: {
            'jquery' : 'vendor/jquery',
            'modernizr' : 'vendor/modernizr',
            'enquire' : 'vendor/enquire',
            'blazyfile' : 'vendor/blazy'
        },
        bundles: {
            'vendor/primary' : ['jquery', 'blazybundled', 'utils']
        },
        shim: {
            'jquery' : {
                exports: '$'
            },
            'blazybundled' : {
                exports: 'Blazy'
            },
            'blazyfile' : {
                exports: 'Blazy'
            },
            'foundation' : {
                deps: ['jquery']
            }
        }
    });
```

Here I am trying to use Blazy:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'blazyfile',
  'utils'
],

function ($, Blazy, utils) {
  'use strict';

  var bLazy = new Blazy({ offset: 500 });
});
```